# Selenium python chromedriver wont connect to proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, proxy

I am trying to connect to a proxy, however the browser is not using it and when I check my ip, it is my own ip and not the proxy.
I provided a fake IP, as my IP is dedicated and private. 
here is what I've tried:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy=https://23.23.23.23:19191'))
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-auth=user:password')
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-type=https')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
driver.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com/")
```

Also, how would i do this on phantomjs?